# Create a unique key from XML

Tags: php, xml, key, unique

### Starting point

I have a small application which stores hardware data from all computers in my network. A powershell script fetches the data and generates an XML therefrom.
This XML is then sent via HTTP request to my PHP script.

On my PHP script I map the data into several objects which are stored in a database (rational).

### Problem

Most of the time I receive always the same XML, because the hardware doesn't change often.

I don't want to split the XML into objects (even if there are libraries for), grab the objects from database and then compare.

### Desired solution

I create a unique key which represents the XML (the XML isn't really big, max 80 lines). This key get stored in the database and each time I only have to compare this key. If it's the same, I don't have to make any updates.

I am grateful for each proposal.

Comment: You tried `md5_file` http://php.net/md5_file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check difference between to objects (by object I mean a text file, a song, an XML file, anything that is a stream of bytes), you can use a hash function.

The goal of a hash function is to compute a "unique" data that identify a content, without storing the content. It is often far shorter than the content (128 bytes for example). The most known is md5. It will compute a md5 hash (a string of 16-byte that you can store in your database alongside your data.

Here a basic pseudocode on how to do it:

```
// Compute the md5 hash of the data you have just received
$hash = md5($data);
// Check if the hash is the same as the one stored into your database
sql_query(<select last hash for your machine>)
// Different data, update into database
if ($last_hash != $hash) {
     // Store the new hash in database & your new content
     sql_query(<update your document with $data and $hash>)
 } else {
      // $hash == $last_hash, content has not changed, do nothing
 }
```

The PHP function you need to compute your md5 hash is [md5](http://php.net/md5).